# Node Express Authentication/authorisation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, authorization

i am just a beginning, with node/express and i kinda have a problem.
i have built a todo application using, node js express and mongo db which actually has an login/register form...i.e, u get to register and login (/register) and(/login) before you can get access to the todo application(/todoapp).
My problem is, if user A logs in with his email and password, inputs some todos and logout, later on user B also get to login with his own different email and password, he gets to see the todos of user A.
but then i want it to be different, user A should be able to see just his own todo, user B should also be able to see just his own todos, please how do i do that?

Please my algorithm is below
-user registers (/register)
-user gets redirected to (/login)
***successfully logins and gets to (/todos)

this works perfectly and sends all logged in users to the same (/todo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you need to store the user _id in a session or a cookie (in the client side) when the user login successfully, then when the user make get/post request first you check if the _id in his seesion/cookie match to the _id in the db and sending back to the user only the items with his _id (items that belong to the user).
you can register a session when the user logs in but keep in mind you must to protect against csrf.

You can also use JWT for this.

I will suggest you to find good tutorial for JWT or authorisation with session and csrf protect.

Its a big subject and its better to watch a good video or read a good article than copy paste code from here.